# Date format error ssis 2010 to excel 2013

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, ssis, etl

I have an SSIS 2010

I have a Date formatted as 01/08/2016 in SQL Server 2012.

```
cast (DateColumn as Date) as DateColumn
```

but when this sent to and excel destination via SSIS is adding ' before the date as ... '01/08/2016

I have used a data conversion from the SSIS toolbox to  help it, but same happens

any ideas please team to resolve this issue?

please help

Comment: Because putting a single tick mark like that indicates that the content is text. If you want a date then send a date, not a formatted string.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the single quotation is used in excel to force a text format over content. It prevent Excel from automatically casting the cell value to another type.

Make sure you are not using an Excel template, were cells format is `text`, make sure that all columns format is `General`. Also, right click on the Excel Destination and check the External Columns metadata, and try to change the column data type to `DT_DATE`.

Comment: I have tried all of the above with no joy . please help